# How to view the method members of a class within a jar file thru the command line

Tags: java, shell, command-line, cmd, dos

I am trying to look at the method members of a class within a jar file. Currently to list all the classes within a jar file, one can call this command:

jar -tf myjar.jar but if i want to list the public methods within a particular class in this jar file, How do i go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be via the [`javap` JDK command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've quickly just hacked this together. Works in Bash/UNIX - I know you tagged this with Dos so probably wanted that, sorry:

```
export CLASSPATH=<JAR>
jar tvf <JAR> | awk '{print $8}' | grep class$ | sed 's/\.class$//' | xargs javap
```

Where `<JAR>` is the name of the jar you want to examine.